# Set a class property to True when appending an item to another property

Tags: python-3.x

I have a class that is defined like that :

```
class Problem:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.has_problem = False
        self.fail = []
        self.critical = []
        self.serious = []
        self.mild = []
```

After I instantiate the class:

```
problem = Problem()
```

I would like to know if there is a way that if I do :

```
problem.fail.append(something)
```

`problem.has_problem` sets itself to `True` automatically.

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If `Problem.has_problem` only reflects whether or not `Problem.fail` is non-empty, you could simply make it a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Problem:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fail = []
        ...

    @property
    def has_problem() -> bool:
        return bool(self.fail)
```

You can then access `has_problem` using the usual attribute syntax, e.g.

```
p = Problem()

if p.has_problem:
    ...
```

This approach can be easily extended if your condition for "having a problem" becomes more complicated in the future. For example, you may have

```
    def has_problem() -> bool:
        categories = (self.critical, self.serious, self.mild)

        return (bool(self.fail)
            or any(len(c) > 3 for c in categories)
            or self._cat_on_fire
        )
```

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking there could be a method like __setattr__ but for appending to a list but this works as well

Answer (score 1):

You could create a method that adds `something` to fail and updates `has_problem` e.g.

```py
class Problem:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.has_problem = False
        self.fail = []
        self.critical = []
        self.serious = []
        self.mild = []

    def add_fail(self, failure):
        self.fail.append(failure)
        self.has_problem = True
```

You would then call the method like so:

```
problem.add_fail(something)
```